# Can I export the live charts from Locust? If not is it possible to fetch the data generated by Locust and store it to use afterwards?

Tags: load-testing, locust, stress-testing

I am running load testing of my back-end using Locust, I want the charts to be imported live on my own UI so developers don't have to switch between multiple windows.

If fetching the charts is not possible, at least can I export the live data somewhere on my machine?

I am still searching for the answer. If I have any update I will surely share it here

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this. One way to do it is using [Event listeners](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html) to send the data off somewhere. The [Locust Plugins project](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins#listeners) has several examples but you can make your own. Assuming you're running in distributed mode you can use the `worker_report` event to trigger a report off to your another DB, like whatever you may be using for your normal backend stats. Depending on how many worker nodes you're using, that could be a lot of load on the DB still. You could maybe also use the `init` or `test_start` events to spawn your own greenlet that runs and reports stats at certain intervals like every 2 seconds. That's what the Locust Plugin examples do.